# UIImage saved file too big

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Trying to understand image sizes on iOS when saved to file.

I have a picture on the iPhone which is 5.1 MB in size. I get this image via the UIImagePickerController in its delegate:

```
let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
```

I save this picture to a folder with the following function:

```
extension UIImage
{
    func save(at url: URL,
              createSubdirectoriesIfNeed: Bool = true,
              compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1.0)  -> URL?
    {
        do
        {
            if createSubdirectoriesIfNeed
            {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url.deletingLastPathComponent(),
                                                        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                        attributes: nil)
            }
            guard let data = jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality) else { return nil }
            print ("Imagesize = \(data.count) Bytes")
            
            var finalurl = url
            if finalurl.pathExtension.isEmpty
            {
                finalurl.appendPathExtension("jpg")
            }
            print (finalurl)
            try data.write(to: finalurl)
            return url
        }
        catch
        {
            print("-- Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now the output from the  `print ("Imagesize = \(data.count) Bytes")`says about 10 MB.
Why has the image doubled in size ?

Comment: I think you should just copy/save the file you previously loaded in the UIImage, rather than convert the image to jpeg before saving. You already have the data, right? Since you're displaying it. Then save that data, instead of saving a new image representation of the data.

Comment: You are saving the file in `.jpg` format with `compressionQuality == 1` -- likely, the original file is using a lower compression quality.

Comment: Good point with just copying the url. Thanks. And it seems that the original picture used 0.9 for compression, as my saved file will get about the correct size when I use 0.9 myself.